# What is the meaning of "field of constants"?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth proper variety over a field $k$, and let $D \subset X$ be a smooth irreducible divisor.

What is the meaning of "the field of constants of $D$"?

Here is my guess: $D$ is proper, so $\Gamma(D, \mathcal{O}_D)$ is a field, actually a finite extension of $k$ (e.g., if $X$ is a curve and $D$ is a point, it is the residue field $k(x)$).

Is this correct? Are there other ways to think of it?

Comment: Can you explain the context? I would say it's just $k$.

Comment: No, because $D$ does not need to be $k$-rational. I've seen this expression in several places, but I had been unable to find a definition. It appears for example in http://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.0128v3.pdf, page 24, line 6

Comment: In this paper at least, my guess is the same as yours.